# workspace created in memory - can't access symbolinfo

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am creating a workspace in memory for unit testing purposes, but I cannot access the symbol info of a certain InvocationExpression (which is required for the CodeIssue I am testing). Here is a simplified example of a test that fails. Please help?

```
        var solution =
            Solution.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId())
                    .AddCSharpProject(Title, Title, out projectId)
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("Microsoft.CSharp"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Core"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Web"))
                    .AddDocument(projectId, "MyFile.cs",
                        @"using System.Web;
                        public partial class _Default : Page
                        {
                            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, string s)
                            {
                                Response.Write(""hello"");
                            }
                        }"
                    , out documentId);



        var mydocument = solution.GetDocument(documentId);
        var tree = mydocument.GetSyntaxTree();
        var model = mydocument.GetSemanticModel();
        var responseWriteLine = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodesAndSelf().First(x => x.GetLocation().GetLineSpan(false).StartLinePosition.Line == 5 && x is InvocationExpressionSyntax);

        Assert.IsNotNull(model.GetSymbolInfo(responseWriteLine.Expression).Symbol);
```

Comment: Which ctp are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added some usings to the code snippet which were missing.

```
 var solution =
            Solution.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId())
                    .AddCSharpProject(Title, Title, out projectId)
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("Microsoft.CSharp"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Core"))
                    .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Web"))
                    .AddDocument(projectId, "MyFile.cs",
                        @"using System;
                        using System.Web;
                        using System.Web.UI;

                        public partial class _Default : Page
                        {
                            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, string s)
                            {
                                Response.Write(""hello"");
                            }
                        }"
                    , out documentId);



            var mydocument = solution.GetDocument(documentId);
            var tree = mydocument.GetSyntaxTree();
            SemanticModel model = (SemanticModel)mydocument.GetSemanticModel();

            var responseWriteLine = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().First();
            Assert.IsNotNull(model.GetSymbolInfo(responseWriteLine.Expression).Symbol);
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up my dodgy code! It looks to be working now. :) FWIW, I am using the September 2012 CTP.